# postgresql nextval incorrect result

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-sequence

After restoring database I run next query

```
SELECT nextval('table_id_seq')
```

and I must get max id + 1 something like (`select max(id) + 1 from table`), but instead I get just max id next time I call it result is correct. This issue happens only to two tables the rest works okay. I use PostgreSQL 10.

Any ideas what it can be.

Comment: Why do you think `nextval()` should return `max() + 1`?

Comment: Because this is what described in documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-sequence.html

Comment: This might actually be a little restore bug in postgres and you need to reset the serial/sequence.  https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Fixing_Sequences

Answer (score 2):

Check "last value" of sequence using below query:

select * from sequence_name

If the last value does not match with table max value then use alter sequence and restart the last value as table max value.